How can I fix or reset a broken plasma-x11 login?
I am was a happy Plasma-X11 user on ubuntu 22.04 until logging in crashes the UI.
Scenario that breaks every time:

On the login screen, I select my username, select the plasma-x11 DM and login with my password.
Screen goes black, no mouse cursor, stays black and borks the UI
I can recover by ssh and sudo systemctl restart gdm

But plasma still works for other logins on the same system, i.e. selecting the plasma-x11 DM before logging in.
And I can login with my broken user id using other DMs, e.g. "ubuntu".
I've gone thru the syslog and am not finding any glaring differences between events when I login with my borked id and a working id.
Is there a way to reset my plasma config for my user id? Is it trying to recover network mounts or open applications that are hanging up?
EDIT: included syslog of point where failed login occurs

Please include your logfiles

By any chance, can you login to the guest session?

I don't have guest sessions enabled, but I do have two other user names that both work for logging into plasma-x11. Only my main id fails. Looking the the xorg and syslog logs, I can't see where the problem is. All the logs show some problems, but those so far look innocent.
I haven't found a place to increase verbosity logging -- yet.
